# Android OpenGLES 2.0 loading more textures

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I want to load more than one textures in OpenGL and use them.

This is TextureLoader,i think it correctly loads texture on idx position.

```
public  int[] texture = new int[10];
public  int loadTexture(Context context, int resource,int idx){

    GLES20.glGenTextures(idx, texture, 0);

    BitmapFactory.Options bo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    Bitmap tex = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resource, bo);

    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, tex, 0);
    tex.recycle();

    if(texture[idx] == 0){
        // Displays error
    }
    return texture[idx];

}
```

This is my render and I have no idea how to select loaded texture.

```
      int mPositionHandle = 
            GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(riGraphicTools.sp_Image, "vPosition");

      GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

      GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, 3,
                                     GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                                     0, vertexBuffer);

      int mTexCoordLoc = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(riGraphicTools.sp_Image, 
                           "a_texCoord" );

      GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray ( mTexCoordLoc );

      // Prepare the texturecoordinates
      GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer ( mTexCoordLoc, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
                    false,
                    0, uvBuffer);

      int mtrxhandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(riGraphicTools.sp_Image, 
                         "uMVPMatrix");

      GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mtrxhandle, 1, false, m, 0);

      int mSamplerLoc = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation (riGraphicTools.sp_Image, 
                          "s_texture" );

      GLES20.glUniform1i ( mSamplerLoc, 0);

      GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length,
               GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);

      GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
      GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mTexCoordLoc);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have most of what you need, assuming that you filled the buffers with the necessary data. There's one call in your code where the arguments are not what you must have intended:

```
GLES20.glGenTextures(idx, texture, 0);
```

With the Java bindings in Android, the first argument is the number of ids you want to generate, the second an array of ids, the 3rd the start index in the array where the generated ids are stored. So to generate one id, and store it as `texture[idx]`, the correct arguments are:

```
GLES20.glGenTextures(1, texture, idx);
```

Then, for the core part of your question, the call you are looking for is `glBindTexture()`. This call defines which specific texture most texture-related OpenGL operations use. You will need this call in multiple places.

- In your `loadTexture()` method, both `GLES20.glTexParameteri()` and `GLUtils.texImage2D()` operate on the currently bound texture. So before those calls, you need to add this call to bind your new texture:

  ```
  GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[idx]);
  ```
- You need the same call before the draw operation. So somewhere in your render method, before you call `GLES20.glDrawElements()`, use a `glBindTexture()` call that looks just like the one above, with the `idx` value of the texture you want to use. This is where you really choose which of the textures you loaded is applied during rendering.

There are mechanisms that allow you to bind multiple textures at the same time. This is mainly useful if your shader needs to sample from multiple textures. You most likely won't need this yet. But once you get to that point, you will want to read up on "texture units", and look up the `glActiveTexture()` call.